# Chat balloons - iOS - Android

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing a chat style app. I can't make the balloons grow or shrink according to the text..

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this? My code currently is as follows:

```
var scrollTxtResp = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  contentWidth: 'auto',
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  layout: 'vertical',
  showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
  top:0,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%'
});  
view.add(scrollTxtResp);  
  var lblTexto = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
 left: 2,
 width: '98%',
 height: 'auto',
 textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
 text: Dec(json[pos].content),
 color: clr_aux5,
 font: { fontFamily: font_primaria, fontSize: 15 }
});
scrollTxtResp.add(lblTexto);
```

[image: Screenshot]

I am using classic Development with SDK 5.2.2 GA ( iOS / Android )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also two modules that will create bubble views:

- iOS: https://github.com/k0sukey/TiBubbleView
- Android: https://github.com/tdtsh/TiBubbleViewForAndroid

They'll create a view that you can fill with e.g. labels:

```
var TiBubble = require('be.k0suke.tibubble');
var bubble = TiBubble.createView({
    top: 0,
    left: 10,
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE, // just fit from contained label
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE, // just fit from contained label
    bubbleColor: '#dfdee5', // default: #fff
    bubbleRadius: 20, // default: 20
    bubbleBeak: TiBubble.BUBBLE_BEAK_LEFT // default BUBBLE_BEAK_LEFT
    bubbleBeakVertical: TiBubble.BUBBLE_BEAK_UPPER // default BUBBLE_BEAK_LOWER
});
bubble.add(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a loot at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

9-Patch images that what you are looking for.

Comment: https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/146449/how-do-i-make-a-view-with-a-bubble-but-with-a-continuous-border